# Atomic array in C11

Tags: c, atomic, c11, stdatomic

Based on the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic), the `_Atomic` type specifier can not be used on arrays. Is there a standard way/workaround to be able to issue `atomic_exchange` calls for an object that is stored within the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard prohibits to apply the `_Atomic` specifier to an array as a whole, for example this

```
typedef double at[5];
_Atomic(at) atomic_array; // constraint violation
```

But the array elements may well be atomic

```
_Atomic(double) atomic_array[5]; // valid
```

If you want the access to the array as a whole to be atomic, you'd have to encapsulate the array within a structure and then have the `_Atomic` around the structure.

Comment: Of course only very objects can be lock-free, like up to 8 or 16 bytes depending on the platform.  16 bytes on new enough AArch64 for atomic ldp/stp without LL/SC, or x86-64 that supports AVX (because that implies 16-byte atomicity for pure-load and pure-store, at least on Intel, without needing lock cmpxchg16b for load/store.)  So a `_Atomic struct { double a[5]; };` would just be using a lock for you to copy the whole array in helper functions every time you did anything with it.  Now a `struct { char c[8];}` would be a different matter entirely, and would be lock-free on most systems.

Comment: Thank you - this definitely answers my question. A follow-up question would be: it appears that GCC thinks that when I take the address of an element from within the array, the resulting element is `_Atomic const type*`. Is there a way to obtain a non-const pointer? Would that be resolved if the memory was not an array but a dynamically allocated memory instead?

Comment: @DanielLovasko, I don't know about that, sounds strange. Atomic and const at the same time is really exotic, so there must be something else going on.